# C++ future: check for validity before calling wait_for()

Tags: c++, future

I was reading about C++ `std::future` and `std::future<T>::wait_for` at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for and the documentation states:

> The behavior is undefined if valid() is false before the call to this function.

However, the sample code reported there:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
 
int main()
{
    std::future<int> future = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
        return 8;
    });
 
    std::cout << "waiting...\n";
    std::future_status status;
    do {
        switch(status = future.wait_for(1s); status) {
            case std::future_status::deferred: std::cout << "deferred\n"; break;
            case std::future_status::timeout: std::cout << "timeout\n"; break;
            case std::future_status::ready: std::cout << "ready!\n"; break;
        }
    } while (status != std::future_status::ready);
 
    std::cout << "result is " << future.get() << '\n';
}
```

calls `wait_for()` on `future` without checking for its validity.
Couldn't this be technically undefined behavior?

The reference on `std::future<T>::valid` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/valid sates that:

> Checks if the future refers to a shared state.
>
> This is the case only for futures that were not default-constructed or
> moved from (i.e. returned by std::promise::get_future(),
> std::packaged_task::get_future() or std::async()) until the first time
> get() or share() is called.

However, I am having difficulties understanding the quoted part. Does that mean that I can assume futures returned by `std::async()` to be valid?

Comment: You don't default construct or move the future, and you don't call `wait_for()` after `get()`, so you are ok.

Comment: Only if you know you havn't previously called `get()` or `share()` on it. Which in the simple example we have not.

Comment: `Valid` is the case only for futures that were not default-constructed or moved from (i.e. returned by std::promise::get_future(), std::packaged_task::get_future() or std::async()) until the first time get() or share() is called. `Not Valid` after the first time get() or share() is called.

Comment: @JinesiYelizati ok, my future is not default-constructed. But it is returned by `std::asynch()`, right? So is my last assumption in the question correct?

Comment: @godo yes, future returned by `std::async()` is `valid`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::future::valid()` returns `true` when the future has an associated *shared state*:

> [19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/futures#unique_future-19)
>
> ```
> bool valid() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Returns:* `true` only if `*this` refers to a shared state.

And `std::async(launch policy, F&& f, Args&&... arg)` returns a `future` with an associated *shared state*:

> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/futures.async#3)
>
> *Effects:* The first function behaves the same as a call to the second function with a policy argument of `launch::async | launch::deferred` and the same arguments for `F` and `Args`. The second function ***creates a shared state*** that is associated with the returned `future` object.
> . . .

So you can rest assured that the `future` returned from `async` is valid.